# GWT DevMode don't reload changes on css files

Tags: css, gwt, gradle, gwt-dev-mode

i've set up a GWT project using Gradle as build management and everything is fine. 
I can deploy my project to my local tomcat in eclipse and the application runs as intended.
But if I start the DevMode and change something in my css resources (which are bound as CssResource classes with an @Source annotation), the GWT DevMode doesn't catch it and the css changes are not taken into account.
Am I missing something? I would expect the DevMode to detect changes in .css files during development without having to run a gwt compile again.

Here is an example of how i am using the css resources:

```
public interface XOFooterPanelResource extends FooterPanelResource, ClientBundle {
    @Override
    @Source("XOFooterPanel.css")
    XOFooterPanelStyle style();

    @Override
    @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Horizontal)
    ImageResource footerPanelBackground();

    @Override
    @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Horizontal)
    ImageResource footerPanelBackgroundEndUser();

    @Override
    @Source("footerDelimiter.jpg")
    ImageResource footerDelimiter();
}

public interface XOFooterPanelStyle extends FooterPanelStyle, CssResource {

}
```

As you can see i have my XOFooterPanelStyle interface which extends CssResource. It is used in the XOFooterPanelResource - which extends ClientBundle - by using the @Source annotation with the name of my CSS file.

And here is the part of my gradle build file which is responsible for starting the DevMode:

```
javaexec {
        main = 'com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode'

        jvmArgs = ['-Xmx2048M', '-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M']

        classpath {
            [
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
                // Java source
                sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir,
                // Generated resources
                sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                // Generated classes
                sourceSets.main.compileClasspath       // Deps
            ]
        }

        args = [
                '-startupUrl', 
                'myapp/index.html', 
                '-noserver',
                '-war',
                'build/devmode',
                '-gen',
                'gen'
            ]
        ext.gwtModules.each {
            args += it
        }
    }
```

As mentioned before i'm using tomcat inside eclipse to run the application, so the `-noserver` option is set.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are directly changing the css file that tomcat is referencing, you will not see the changes in dev mode.  I believe that when you deploy via tomcat in eclipse, your code is not referenced directly from the eclipse project workspace, a copy is moved to the tomcat webapps folder.

I'm not sure what the standard way around this is.  I feel like there has to be an option to refresh static resources to the tomcat instance from eclipse, but I haven't looked into it.

Here are two ways i've gotten around the issue when I needed to:

1) You can put CSS code in your ui.xml files, and that should get picked up by devMode.
[Tutorial on how to add css to your ui.xml](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World)

2) You could also modify the css file in the webapps folder directly, then migrate any changes you made back to the workspace version.

Comment: As a workaround use maven-resources-plugin copy-resources, <directory>src/main/webapp</directory><outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/gwt-webapp</outputDirectory>.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Comment: The changes I make to the CSS file in the webapps folder is just not being picked up and on page refresh gwt says `skipped compile because no input files have changed`?